# Models for fully correlated data

Tags: regression, correlation

Problem Statement:

- I am analyzing ageing patients that have some terminal disease. There are multiple patients and they are measured multiple times throughout the study. Each patient is measured a different number of times at different intervals. Patient measurements consist of covariates and responses measured at the same time
- Each time you some new set of covariates measurements, the new set of measurements (eg weight, blood cell count, lung function) will usually be worse. This means that the measurements are correlated (conditional on older measurements) and not independent.
- I have two response variables:
- Response 1:  the stage of the disease on the date of measurement (eg which stage of cancer, ie stage 1, stage2, stage3, stage4), the response variable for the same patient will be correlated to older response values for the same patient as well (eg usually disease stage can either remain still or go down ... very rarely reverses).
- Response 2: The cumulative total amount of money spent by the patients insurance provider from the start of the study up to the date of measurement
- There is correlation in both the response and the covariates.

Goals:

- I am interested in creating a statistical model to study different ideas, e.g. effect of covariates on disease stage over periods of time, transition between disease stages for different cohorts of patients, effect of the covariates on disease stage transition, etc.  I am interested in creating another statistical model to estimate the associative effect of worsening patient health on the amount of insurance paid.

Obstacles:

- However, I worry that there might be large (and hidden) correlations within my data that will violate model assumptions.
- Are there any statistical models that be used for fully correlated data (ie correlation within responses and correlation with covariates)?
- Usually, basic regression assumes that the covariates are have 0 correlation and the response  has 0 correlation.
- Longitudinal (mixed effects) regression can handle situations where the response variable is correlated for each subject. But the covariates are assumed to have 0 correlation.

Closing thoughts:

- Are there any statistical models that can handle correlation within the covariates and responses (ie correlation within responses and correlation with covariates)?
- I read about Joint Survival Model which I think might be applicable for this type of situation (provided I have survival data)? But is there something in general I can use?
- I know there is something called Multi State Models (MSM) ... but I am not sure if these can be used for continuous variables (eg cumulative insurance money spent) without the variable being discretized. But I dont want to discretize a continuous variable.

PS: I was also wondering - what about "time between measurements" for the same patient? Can the effect of this factor be introduced in the model? Correlation might be larger in certain situations (eg when left without treatment, the health of old and sick patients gets worse and worse exponentially ...regardless if you measure it or not). The strength of the correlation can also increase/decrease with time and is likely influenced by previous values of the response/covariates for the same patient ... and somewhat reflected by similar trends in similar patients. I hate to sound harsh, but unfortunately this is the sad truth of life :(. This is why we must work to develop better medicine technologies to help people in need.

Comment: You might want to look into multilevel models AKA mixed effect models AKA hierarchical models when considering the repeated measurements part of your question.

Comment: The last paragraph suggests you are dealing with a non-stationary stochastic process.

Comment: `basic regression assumes that the covariates are have 0 correlation` I don’t agree with the way I interpret this claim. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dave there is nothing to elaborate, it is just wrong

Comment: "In statistics, errors-in-variables models or measurement error models are regression models that account for measurement errors in the independent variables. In contrast, standard regression models assume that those regressors have been measured exactly, or observed without error; as such, those models account only for errors in the dependent variables, or responses" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models)

Comment: Joint models / models with one or more hidden states (general health or health of specific organs that's correlated) that realize themselves into multiple observable outcomes seem like options for this sort of thing.

Comment: can I place a bounty here?

Comment: @U_texas_2023 I would advise against that, as the question has gotten attention, and issuing a bounty would drop your reputation below that required to comment. You will be best off by clarifying the question. For instance, you have not responded to my comment from a few days ago.

Comment: I did elaborate. see the wiki quote?

Comment: @U_texas_2023 How do you see that as a response to my question?

Comment: sorry, let me clarify. in a longitudinal regression model, you can choose a correlation structure for the response variable (ex: autoregressive). But you can never choose a correlation for the covariates. what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Your question includes aspects of basic longitudinal data analysis, time-series analysis, and multi-state time-to-event analysis. Each of those is complicated enough; combining them can be even trickier.

As you seem to be starting out with this type of study, I recommend that you find an experienced local expert to help with this. There is no way that a question-and-answer site like this can provide enough help.

Here are links to some general principles to understand and apply, which should make your conversations with a statistician more fruitful.

You seem already to understand of the role of serial correlation with single outcome variables, as indicated by your [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632449/28500). Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long) is a useful introduction to the general problem of dealing with longitudinal responses, discussing the relative advantages of several approaches. Note that standard mixed modeling can make hidden and potentially invalid assumptions about serial correlations.

The problem of multiple *types* of correlated observations over time, which you seem to be getting at in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632406/28500), is addressed by [time-series analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/time-series/info). [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos is an accessible resource. The simplest methods rely on having evenly spaced observations in time, which you don't seem to have. Nevertheless, understanding those simplest methods will help you understand the additional considerations with unevenly spaced observations.

Time-to-event analysis is sometimes just called "survival analysis" for simplicity. Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* starting from [Chapter 17](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/surv) is a good introduction to the principles. As explained in vignettes for the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival), the methods are readily extended to [time-varying covariate values](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) and to [multiple types of events](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf). [Chapter 22](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov) of *Regression Modeling Strategies* explains approaches that are particularly helpful with ordered outcomes, as for cancer stages.

An important trick with time-varying covariates in time-to-event analysis is finding an appropriate model of the association between covariate *history* and event risk. Simple models associate the *current* values of covariates with *current* risk of an event (e.g., a step up in cancer stage). What's more likely, however, is that some integrated or rolling-average measure of past covariate values is what's associated with current event risk. That requires applying your understanding of the subject matter.

A properly constructed joint model of covariates over time and times-to-events should be able to put all this together, in principle. The R [Survival Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Survival) has links to many tools for constructing such models. As you seem to be starting out with this type of analysis, I'd recommend that you study and apply Bayesian approaches to this problem. My sense is that Bayesian approaches are increasingly favored over frequentist approaches, although I'm certainly not an expert on that.

The [`rstanarm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstanarm) in R is one choice for implementation; it has a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/jm.html) specifically on joint models. The vignette doesn't seem to illustrate a multi-state model like you would seem to need, but it should provide a useful introduction to principles that can then be extended to more complex scenarios.