# Correlation structure for covariate variables in longitudinal regression

Tags: regression

In longitudinal regression(ex: repeated measures for different people), we have the option to choose a correlation structure for the response variable. For example (https://youtu.be/qoqhPq_VILc?si=yJmlrWR4hlgOz1IL):

[image]

But is it ever possible to have these kinds of correlation structures for the independent variables? I suspect that in many scenarios, the independent variables (covariates) are also correlated for the same subject from measurement to measurement.

For example, in geriatric overweight patients, the patient weight (kilograms) almost always increases from measurement to measurement for the same patient (ie correlated). Thus, for the same patient, the weight variable is not IID  .... which can be a violation of assumptions.

Is there any modelling approach I can use for longitudinal regression (repeated measures) when I suspect that the independent variables have some correlation? Can I specify a correlation structure as well?

Comment: In what circumstances would the distribution of the independent variables matter?  For most regression problems it's irrelevant (partly because regression, almost by definition, concerns *conditional* distributions of the response rather than the full multivariate distribution of explanatory and response variables).

Answer (score 0):

One option may be an autoregressive/cross-lagged path analytic model. In that type of model, all variables (including covariates) would have autoregressive paths thus taking into account auto-correlation across measurement occasions. See, for example:

Selig, J. P., & Little, T. D. (2012). Autoregressive and cross-lagged panel analysis for longitudinal data. In B. Laursen, T. D. Little, & N. A. Card (Eds.), Handbook of developmental research methods (pp. 265–278). The Guilford Press.